# Proper HTTP status code to send on application error

Tags: http, error-handling, http-headers

I'm reviewing the class that handles all the errors in my PHP application.

I'm serving these headers depending on the type of the error to handle:

- 404 in case of page not found or existing page with a wrong/not anymore available item;
- 500 for server errors;
- 503 + Retry-after for temporary maintenance

I'm still uncertain on which header to send on application errors: SQL query errors, programming errors (PHP-core errors, classes exceptions, etc...). Of course these kind of errors shouldn't occur because of the development tests and beta-testing done on every page, but who knows, maybe they could occur.

I can't decide which one to adopt among:

- **400 Bad Request** Actually these kind of situations are "Good" requests, it's just that we made mistakes on programming.
- **403 Forbidden** Actually, the resource is not forbidden... You can (and should be able to) access to it.
- **500 Internal Server Error** Maybe it could be the best option, but it's not properly and specifically a server error, but an application error. The server is OK!

I didn't find any answer here in Stackoverflow nor around blogs: everyone is wondering which header to send on 404 cases, on server errors or on maintenance statuses, but nobody suggested a solution about application errors.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From HTTP's point of view, what you call "application" is part of the server.

Comment: Yes. 4xx is for client errors, 5xx for server errors.